# If sigma bonds are stronger than pi bonds, why are the BDE's lower and the bonds longer?

Tags: bond, energy

If sigma bonds are stronger than pi bonds, why then do we say that the triple bonds which have 2 pi bonds are stronger than single bonds?

Answer (score 8):

Some points to clarify:

1. Sigma bonds is indeed stronger than pi bonds.
2. Therefore, sigma bonds have a **lower** energy than pi bonds (although sigma bonds do indeed have a higher **dissociation** energy than pi bonds).
3. Double bonds (usually) contain $1$ sigma bond and $1$ pi bond.
4. Triple bonds (usually) contain $1$ sigma bond and $2$ pi bond.

From this, you can see why the triple bond has a higher (dissociation) energy than a single bond: because a triple bond contains three bonds, one of which is the sigma bond also present in the single bond.